# Find a prime number $p$ so that the polynomial $f(X) = X^ 4 + X ^3 + 3X + (p - 2) $ is divisible by $ X - 2 $ in $\mathbb Z_p[X]. $

Tags: polynomials

> Find a prime number $p$ so that the polynomial $f(X) = X^ 4 + X ^3 + 3X + (p - 2) $ is divisible by $X - 2$ in $\mathbb Z_p[X]$.

My solution:

Let $f(x)= (x-2)(x^3 +ax^2 +bx +c )$. By comparing the coefficients $ a-2=1 ,b-2a=0 , c-2b=3 $ and $-2c= p-2 $.

Then p=-28 This not prime.
Why i have got p= -28???

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just compute $f(2)$, which is $p+28$. So we have $p+28 = 0$ in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, which means you have $p \in \{2,7\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much .. MooS